# How do you disable hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling via the command line in Windows 10/11?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, gpu

I need to disable, programmatically, hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling in Windows if it's enabled.

[image: UI settings for HW-accelerated GPU scheduling]

Searching, I was pointed at the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers` - `HwSchMode` regkey.  This is `2` when HW GPU scheduling is enabled and `1` after disabling via the settings UI.

I've tried just setting this regkey to 1 and rebooting, but while this key remains changed after reboot, HW accelerated GPU scheduling is still enabled.

Is there any other method to disable this that isn't the UI?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was using `REG_SZ` instead of `REG_DWORD` when setting the value.  Once I changed my code to use this instead, everything started working as expected.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers]
"HwSchMode"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Cool, will save it to my bookmarks, have a good one :)